# How to separate interface from implementation

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Is it possible to separate interface from implementation where the client assembly has no idea of the actual implementation and works only on the interfaces. If we offload the object creation to another component, it will still create a dependency on the actual implementation types.

I can think of doing this using reflection where a layer is responsible for serving the objects which are cast as interfaces. The actual instantiation of the types are done through reflection and stored in a dictionary where the key is the interface and value the implementation object. This way the client code has no idea of the type of implemenation.

Is there a design pattern to do this without reflection?

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: The design pattern is "Inversion of Control", I'd imagine reflection is used under the hood.

Comment: Did you try MEF and/or a ServiceLocator?

Comment: Thanks George,  I will go over to dofactory and check if it solved my problem

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson My application is in 3.5 :( MEF is not an option. I will check out the Service Locator pattern

Comment: I would not recommend using the Service Locator pattern: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Comment: The Abstract factory solves my problem. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is useful in scenario of *dynamic* allocation, for example in case of plugin-based systems. If you don't want to manage that kind of environment, just declare all implementaions in the code and use only interface in consumer.

The thing is, that in both cases, in some point there have to be "someone" who decides which *real* type to create. In case of plugin-based logic it could be, say, `PluginManager`, in other case would be some `factory` method/calss.

Design pattern is [IoC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29271/Design-pattern-Inversion-of-control-and-Dependency), if you're ineterested in.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you describe here is called IOC(inversion of control container) - except reflection you can use configuration(in app/web.config) or bootstrapping via code.

Take a look at some popular IOCs like [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net) and [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is called Inversion of Control (IoC). The most common application of this is known as Dependency Injection (DI).

You may find the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://manning.com/seemann/) a valuable resource on this topic.